# Using querySelector in VueJS unit tests logs error

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, vue.js, karma-jasmine, vuejs2

When writing unit tests I keep getting a massive stack strace any time I use the `querySelector()` on that component. The test still passes but just throws and error. Here's my spec for a default Hello component:

Hello.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h1, h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Hello.spec.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'

describe('Hello.vue', () => {
 it('should render correct contents', () => {
  const vm = new Vue(Hello).$mount()
  expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.hello h1').textContent)
   .toEqual('Welcome to Your Vue.js App')
 })
})
```

Package.json

```
{
 "vue": "^2.2.2",
 "karma": "^1.6.0",
 "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
 "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
}
```

Error:

`ERROR LOG: TypeError{stack: 'render@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:80741:28
get@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:5337:29
evaluate@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:5437:24
computedGetter@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:5681:25
render@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:91018:131
_render@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:6477:26
updateComponent@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:5026:28
get@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:5337:29
Watcher@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:5320:15
mountComponent@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:5030:28
$mount@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:10120:24
$mount@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:12169:20
http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?6c531a43b44d6e4b9f5a01ea1fbbc3a4597aeae5:43223:64
attemptSync@http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/user/projects/my-project/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d:1950:28
run@http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/user/projects/my-project/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d:1938:20...`

Comment: What is the complete error? I believe this is the default unit test that you get with vue-cli scaffolding?

Comment: Just popped it up top, thanks for looking at it 

Comment: Can you also post the `Hello` component?

Comment: Sure thing, It's just the default one, but added it up top

Comment: Have you tried getElementsByClassName, instead of querySelector by giving a class name to h1 element?